# How can i generate the columns based on group and number of items?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I have data under different categories.
Ex: Salads, Desserts

I want to group them based on category and also only 5 items per column.

```
 <div>
<h3>Salads</h3>
<div>
salad 0
salad 1
salad 2
salad 3
salad 4
</div>
<div>
salad 5
salad 6
salad 7
salad 8
salad 9
salad 10
</div>
<div>
salad 11
</div>
</div>

    <div> 
    <h3> Desserts</h3>
<div>
Dessert 1
Dessert 2
Dessert 3
Dessert 4
Dessert 5
</div>

    <div>
    Dessert 6
    </div>

        </div>
```

How can I achieve it using php ? Need help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code i'm using. The issue with this code is, if the category has even number of items, it is not working. If odd number of items, then it perfectly works.

```
    $itemsperrow = 2;

$sql_menugrouptbl = "SELECT category FROM ck_menulist GROUP BY category ORDER BY id";
$result = $conn->query($sql_menugrouptbl);
$result->execute(); 
echo "Total category: ". $result->rowcount(); 

foreach($result as $row){

    $categ = $row['category'];



    $sql_menulisttbl = "SELECT * FROM ck_menulist WHERE category  = '$categ'";
    $stmt = $conn->Prepare($sql_menulisttbl); 
    $stmt ->execute();
    $countmenulist = $stmt->rowcount();
    echo "<h1>".$categ." (".$countmenulist.")</h1>"; 

    foreach($stmt as $rowitem){

    if ($countmenulist % $itemsperrow == 1)
    {  
       echo "<div class=\"col-md-4 jt_col column_container\">";    
       echo "<div class=\"voffset10\"></div>";
       echo "<ul class=\"menu\">";
    }
       echo "<li>";
       echo $rowitem['itemname'];
       echo "<div class=\"detail\">".$rowitem['itemdescription']." <span class=\"price\">$ ".$rowitem['price']."</span></div>";
       echo "</li>";

    if ($countmenulist%$itemsperrow == 0)
    {
        echo "\n";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "\n";
    }
    $countmenulist++;

    }



      if ($countmenulist%$itemsperrow != 1) {
            echo "\n";
            echo "</div>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: if the categories are array, you could use `array_chunk($categories, 5)` to split it every 5 items

Comment: It can be loaded into php array. but i'm more looking for the looping code that can do that.

Comment: maybe you could provide the data you want to loop?

Comment: the data is mentioned in the question i posted.

Comment: i mean the php version

Comment: @HastaDhana updated with php code

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the array like below :

```
$sql_menugrouptbl = "SELECT category FROM ck_menulist GROUP BY category ORDER BY id";
$result = $conn->query($sql_menugrouptbl);
$result->execute(); 
echo "Total category: ". $result->rowcount(); 

foreach($result as $row){

    $categ = $row['category'];



    $sql_menulisttbl = "SELECT * FROM ck_menulist WHERE category  = '$categ'";
    $stmt = $conn->Prepare($sql_menulisttbl); 
    $stmt ->execute();
    $countmenulist = $stmt->rowcount();
    echo "<h1>".$categ." (".$countmenulist.")</h1>"; 

    $splitted_item = array_chunk($stmt, $itemsperrow, true);
    foreach($splitted_item as $sub_menu){
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-4 jt_col column_container\">";    
        echo "<div class=\"voffset10\"></div>";
        echo "<ul class=\"menu\">"; 
        foreach($sub_menu as $rowitem){
            echo "<li>";
            echo $rowitem['itemname'];
            echo "<div class=\"detail\">".$rowitem['itemdescription']." <span class=\"price\">$ ".$rowitem['price']."</span></div>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>"; 
        echo "\n";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is giving me only the main category headings but not the items under category.